# Android Studio - Cant find class referenced from project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Have been having this issue with android studio. I have subfolders (packages) and A.Studio seems to not link them properly - or i am doing something wrong

This is my project structure 
[image]

my activity helper class uses ActivityUIHelper class - but A.Studio throws the error

```
Could not find class 'com.mface.mcall.ui.base.ActivityUIHelper', referenced from method com.mface.mcall.ui.base.ActivityHelper.<init>
```

THe complete error log

```
12-31 03:47:39.719    3600-3600/com.mface.mcall E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.mface.mcall.ui.base.ActivityUIHelper', referenced from method com.mface.mcall.ui.base.ActivityHelper.<init>
12-31 03:47:39.729    3600-3600/com.mface.mcall E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/mface/mcall/ui/base/ActivityHelper
            at com.mface.mcall.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:99)
            at com.mface.mcall.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 03:48:17.439    3793-3793/com.mface.mcall E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.mface.mcall.ui.base.ActivityUIHelper', referenced from method com.mface.mcall.ui.base.ActivityHelper.<init>
12-31 03:48:17.449    3793-3793/com.mface.mcall E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/mface/mcall/ui/base/ActivityHelper
            at com.mface.mcall.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:99)
            at com.mface.mcall.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the init section of activityhelper

```
public ActivityHelper(Context context, GlobalActionsListener actionsListener) {
        super(context);
        this.actionsListener = actionsListener;
        activity = (Activity) context;
        Log.d(TAG,activity.toString());
        activityUIHelper = new ActivityUIHelper(activity);
    }
```

This is the main build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
ext.compileSdkVersion = 21
ext.buildToolsVersion = '21.1.2'
ext.minSdkVersion = 14
ext.targetSdkVersion = 21
ext.versionName = '1.0'
ext.versionCode = 25

ext.prodDebug = false
ext.devDebug = true

// Dependencies versions
ext.universalImageLoaderVersion = '1.9.3'
ext.googlePlayServicesVersion = '6.1.+'
ext.croutonVersion = '1.8.4'
ext.cropperVersion = '0.9.10'
ext.viewPagerIndicatorVersion = '2.4.1'
ext.picassoVersion = '2.4.0'
ext.guavaVersion = '18.0'
ext.roundedImageViewVersion = '1.1.0'
ext.stickyListHeadersVersion = '2.5.2'
ext.FButtonVersion ='1.0.5'
ext.croutonVersion = '1.8.5'
```

This is the app's gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'crashlytics'
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':Q-municate_core')
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:${rootProject.googlePlayServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:${rootProject.cropperVersion}@aar"
    compile "com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:${rootProject.universalImageLoaderVersion}"
    compile "fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:${rootProject.viewPagerIndicatorVersion}@aar"
    compile group: 'com.squareup.picasso', name: 'picasso', version: "${rootProject.picassoVersion}"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:${rootProject.guavaVersion}"
    compile "com.makeramen:roundedimageview-apklib:${rootProject.roundedImageViewVersion}"
    compile "se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:${rootProject.stickyListHeadersVersion}"
    compile "info.hoang8f:fbutton:${rootProject.FButtonVersion}"
    compile "de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:${rootProject.croutonVersion}@aar"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.mface.mcall'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

**Tried build, clean from A.Studio menu and command line as well. Did'nt help!**

There are no build errors but the app crashes. This is my first project with gradle and A.Studio and things are not really rosy :(

Comment: any solution found??? facing same problem :(

Comment: i am also facing same problem @Veeru have you found anything